# Preload images - 0 bytes in devtools

Tags: javascript, image, devtools, preloading

I have been trying to preload images in pure Javascript following the ideas of Mark Meyer in https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/image-preloading/, which is exactly what I need.

The function I use is:

```js
function preload(index) {
 index = index || 0;
 if (index < 10) {
  preImage[index] = new Image();
  preImage[index].onload = function() { preload(index+1) };
  preImage[index].src = "img/IMG" + ("0000"+(index+1)).slice(-4)+"A.png";

 };
 return;
}
```

I want to preload images IMG0001A.png through to IMG0009A, in that order. preImage is an empty array.
My problem is that when I see the network activity in Chrome devtools, even though I simulate a slow connection and the cache is disabled, the images show a size of 0 bytes, and, of course, they are 'loaded' just too fast. Can anybody tell me what's going on? thanks in advance

Here is a screenshot of devtools:

[image: Chrome devtools showing images with 0 Bytes in size]

Comment: possibly because the images are in the cache

Comment: The cache is disabled. Just in case, I tried a new set of images, and even though it took a bit longer (57 ms in a slow connection!), they still showed a size of 0 bytes in size!

Comment: have you tried a different browser? firefox for example?

Comment: I haven't tried but I will - thank you for the advise!